# How can I trigger errors on webpages so I can take a screen capture for visual display?

Tags: php, custom-errors

I want to be able to "make" browser display errors, like forbidden, 503 etc...

Is there some kind of sandbox where I could do this?

I need the errors to be rendered in google chrome, then take a screen capture of browser window.

Something like image under it, but force the browser to display something like this, maybe in Chrome dev tools could be done?

[image]

Comment: PHP has `trigger_error` function which will allow you to do this.

Comment: You want to trigger this in your own website or any website that's on the internet?

Comment: "PHP has trigger_error function which will allow you to do this" 

how do I do this?

"You want to trigger this in your own website or any website that's on the internet? " 

As a tool on internet of with Google chrome would be ideal, or could try to hack the Wordpress code with a plugin that allows PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with try-catch condition and set_exception_handler function like this:

```php
<?php

class MyCustomException extends Exception { }

function exception_handler($exception) {
   echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

try {
   throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception');
} catch (MyCustomException $e) {
   echo "Your custom exception caught ";
   echo $e->getMessage();
} finally {
   echo "I'm always here";
}

print "Not executed";
```

For more information you may visit site [https://netgen.io/blog/modern-error-handling-in-php](https://%20https://netgen.io/blog/modern-error-handling-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `try` and `catch`, you can check function inside `try` and throw error to `catch`.

For example, I need to run MySQL if is there any error then report it.

So here is function for it:

```
try {
    if(!mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
        throw new Exception(you can put query error)
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print_r($e)
}
```

The `$e` inside catch will give you error.